# how to set code on input text field in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a auto complete .First I download my data from server and then write anything on text field it filter with my **stationCode**.I have two thing in my json array **stationCode** and **stationName** array .Now I need to set the selected station code on input text field .Can you please tell me what is better way to set the value of station code on input text field whenever user select any row of autosuggest.

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />




</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="cnt">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText.stationCode">
        <table ng-show="searchText.stationCode && searchText.stationCode.length != 0">

            <tr id="$index"ng-repeat= "a in d.data | filter:searchText" ng-click="getselectedRow(searchText)">
                   <td> {{a.stationCode}} </td>
                <td> {{a.stationName}} </td>


            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>



function cnt($scope,$http){
    $http.get("http://184.106.159.143:8180/FGRailApps/jservices/rest/stationList")
        .success(function (data) {
           //alert(data);
            $scope.d=data;
        }).error(function(data){
                              alert("error")
        });

    $scope.getselectedRow=function(obj){
        alert(obj.stationCode)
    }


}
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/66z4dxsy/1/

Please disable web security of browser

Comment: can you provide your code in jsfiddle ?

Comment: I Already given whole code ..I will try

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66z4dxsy/1/     please disable web security before run fiddle

Comment: did you try $scope.d=JSON.parse(data); ?

Comment: Why do we need to 'disable security'? As far as instructions/guidance goes, that's a little worrisome.

Comment: I solve my problem my own thanks for help...I send like that ng-click="getselectedRow(a)..get like that  $scope.getselectedRow=function(obj){
        alert(obj.stationName)
    }

Comment: can you please how to set the text in input field

Comment: in your case searchText.stationCode = "text"

Comment: ok i will try.and tell you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66z4dxsy/2/ I am able to set ..Thanks But i have face one problem that when I click on row it should hide again.In other word.When I run the program my table is hide .when I type on input field it show but when I select it again hide how I will achieve this.Please disable web security

Comment: how to hide after select